# Event observer not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

`//App/Code/Local/Acme/Datecontrol/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Datecontrol>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Acme_Datecontrol>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <datecontrol>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Acme_Datecontrol</module>
                    <frontName>datecontrol</frontName>
                </args>
            </datecontrol>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_before>
                <observers>
                    <Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkDate</method>
                    </Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before> 
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the observer,

`//App/Code/Local/Acme/Datecontrol/Model/Observer.php`:

```
class Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer {

    public function checkDate($observer) {
        Mage::log('Frontend Page loaded', null, 'FirstObserver.log');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Datecontrol>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Acme_Datecontrol>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <datecontrol>
                <class>Acme_Datecontrol_Model</class>
            </datecontrol>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <datecontrol>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Acme_Datecontrol</module>
                    <frontName>datecontrol</frontName>
                </args>
            </datecontrol>
        </routers>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_before> //does not allow type singleton, try using 'controller_action_predispatch' instead
                <observers>
                    <datecontrol_checkdate> //not important
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>datecontrol/observer</class>
                        <method>checkDate</method>
                    </datecontrol_checkdate>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before> 
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. The controller_action_predispatch event is fired on every page reload, right? Also, I tried singleton and model for the 'type' node but to no avail. Any solution?

Comment: Hey, this worked! :D Replacing the acme_datecontrol node under <models> helped. Thanks a bunch, mate! :)

Comment: FYI it would be better to place the whole event in global instead of frontend if you are using 'controller_front_init_before'

Comment: Thank you. Will keep that in mind. I'm using a different event for now, however.

Answer (score 0):

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Datecontrol>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Acme_Datecontrol>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <acme_datecontrol>
                <class>Acme_Datecontrol_Model</class>
            </acme_datecontrol>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <datecontrol>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Acme_Datecontrol</module>
                    <frontName>datecontrol</frontName>
                </args>
            </datecontrol>
        </routers>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_before> //Im not sure for this event
                <observers>
                    <Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer>
                        <class>acme_datecontrol/observer</class>
                        <method>checkDate</method>
                    </Acme_Datecontrol_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before> 
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

On a 1.6.2 version, I had the same problem and I managed to make it work using the events in the **global** node, instead of *frontend* :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Datecontrol>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Acme_Datecontrol>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <datecontrol>
                <class>Acme_Datecontrol_Model</class>
            </datecontrol>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_before>
                <observers>
                    <datecontrol_checkdate>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>datecontrol/observer</class>
                        <method>checkDate</method>
                    </datecontrol_checkdate>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before> 
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <datecontrol>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Acme_Datecontrol</module>
                    <frontName>datecontrol</frontName>
                </args>
            </datecontrol>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```